# Can't add children to Grid when binding to VM with Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I want to add (any) elements to a grid from my view model in my Caliburn.Micro application (it's really a Revit add-in so not quite an application, but should work the same).

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around certain aspects of the MVVM model and binding data to elements in the view...

My ViewModel

```cs
public class MyViewModel : Screen
{
    private Grid _myGrid;
    public Grid MyGrid
    {
        get { return _myGrid; }
        set
        {
            _myGrid = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MyGrid);
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyGrid = new Grid();
        var label = new Label { Content = "Hello!" };
        MyGrid.Children.Add(label); // I know this isn't MVVM but how can I do basically this?
    }
}
```

My View

```xml
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MyView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
        <!-- Here goes stuff from view model -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I know this is all wrong... I need help getting elements into my grid element from the view model.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach you are taking here is wrong as you are creating View elements in your ViewModel. With MVVM, you still want to design your UI (View) in XAML. In your case you would still create the `Grid` and the `Label` in your XAML in most cases. Think of what you are doing with this approach.

You have a data model that stores the data properties and notifies of changes. Think of this as the structural side of the data.

```cs
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string labelValue;
    public string LabelValue
    {
        get { return labelValue; }
        set
        {
            labelValue = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LabelValue);
        }
    }

    //Property changed handler logic below.
    //I assume you have something based on your code.
}
```

Now we create a ViewModel that does stuff with the data. This is what the view is bound too.

```cs
public class MyViewModel
{
    //Add a property for the model you created
    public MyModel NewModel {get;set;}

    //Load the NewModel values when the view model is created.
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        NewModel = new MyModel(){LabelValue="Hello World"};
    }
}
```

Ok so we have a data `Model`, and we have a `ViewModel` to actually use the `Model` and fill it with values. Now lets create the UI (`View`) and bind to the `ViewModel`.

In your `Window` you will create a label and simply bind your desired `ViewModel` property. In this case we will your your models `LabelValue` property.

```xml
<Grid>
     <Label Content="{Binding NewModel.LabelValue}"/>
</Grid>
```

Now we simply set the datacontext in the UI codebehind

```cs
public MyViewModel myViewModel = new MyViewModel(); //Create the ViewModel
public MyWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();  
     //Set the DataContext to the ViewModel
     DataContext = myViewModel;
}
```

When you fire up the program the label content should be whatever you set it as in your `ViewModel` `MyModel.LabelValue` property. This is only a simple explanation of very large concept, but it should give you an idea of how it works. There are also many techniques and styles of MVVM people use, but this concept of is MVVM in its most basic form. Hopefully this gives you an idea and starts you on the right path.

The goal is to run your logic in you `ViewModel` so that the `View`s and `Model`s can be built with minimal code. If you properly implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` all values on your `View` automatically update with no additional code or UI thread locks. Though the concept seems bulky at first, it saves a lot of time and effort in the long run.